# How does window.URL.createObjectURL() deal with browser's file/image cache?

Tags: html, browser-cache

When using the HTTP Authorization header in a web app it's necessary for the client to request any secured image resources via XHR because the  element loads its src URL with no opportunity for the app to intercept the request and add the auth header. This is clearly designed for a cookie-based (forms) auth environment. To get around this limitation the HTML5 URL.createObjectURL() can be used to XHR the image as a blob and assign to the img src programmatically.

This is great, but I'd like to understand how caching works in this case. MDN says:

> Each time you call createObjectURL(), a new object URL is created, even if you've already created one for the same object. Each of these must be released by calling URL.revokeObjectURL()...

The browser will certainly cache images by default, but what does that mean for multiple objectURLs to the same image? Does each new URL instance for the same underlying image resource mean duplicated memory or does that get cached too?